# How to keep a Chrome extension script running

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am unable to correctly trigger an event click with a Chrome extension. The background script:

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "turnon.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"toggle.js"});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "turnoff.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"stoptoggle.js"});
  }
});
```

The script is suppose to toggle every time the body of the page is clicked. It currently does nothing.

```
$('body').on('click',function(){
$('main').toggle();
});
```